# AOSP build not working - failed to build some targets

Tags: android, makefile, build

I am trying to build the AOSP but i always get this error.

[image]

In every thread the answer is that its a RAM problem.
I have tried the build with the following commands. Nothing works

m -j32

m -j16

m -j12

m -j8

m -j2

m -j1

I am using a 32GB 14Core Native Linux Workstation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding 20GB of Swap Storage it now works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).